# How Can I Permanently Change File Extension Associations in IntelliJ IDEA 2017?

Tags: intellij-idea

Simple deal. I change a file extension association in settings, and it works, but Intelli-J IDEA rather unintelligently changes the file extension back to what it was before I set it, everytime the IDE restarts.

I use the file extension for my own development purposes, and I don't need to open files of this type from within Intelli-J, unless I want to edit the file with IntelliJ's text editor.

For whatever reason, I don't get a choice, and cannot find an option to disable this automatic file extension association re-assignment.

`How Can I Permanently Change File Extension Associations in IntelliJ IDEA 2017?`

Comment: The removing the pattern from **registered patterns** in [File types settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-types.html) and assigning it to another file type (i.e. to plain text) should work. What is the file extension and the file type type? Are there any errors in [log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)?

Comment: no log errors. linux os: utf-8-plain-text: ext: .hlp; with wine: WinDOS for *nix.